# How can $\sum_{1}^\infty 1/(n^2) = \pi^2/6$ when $\int_1^\infty 1/(x^2) =1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can $\sum_{1}^\infty 1/(n^2) = \pi^2/6$ when $\int_1^\infty 1/(x^2) =1$ ?

Comment: Is the summation the same as integral?

Comment: The very first term of the series is already $1$: $\frac{1}{1^2}$ is much larger than $\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{x^2}$. On the other hand you can state that $\zeta(2)\leq 1+\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}=2.$

Comment: The summation has only natural number inputs but integral tells us the area which should be sum of f(x) for all real number of x.  So, my question is how can the former be greater than latter.

Comment: This is similar to say why the area of a circle with $r=1$ is grater than the circumference! these are two distinct things.

Comment: Draw a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ is the total area of the (infinite) set of rectangles of height $\frac{1}{n^2}$ with upper left hand corner at $(n,\frac{1}{n^2})$.

$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}$ is the area under a curve which, although it touches those rectangles at all integer values of $x$, lies below the tops of the rectangles whenever $x$ is not an integer.  So you would expect this integral to be a bit less than the sum, and indeed $1 < \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

The integral test will only give qualitative information, i.e., convergence for the series iff the integral is finite. There is no claim whatsoever that the values are the same! Your example is a good illustration of that!